# Not able to send SMS using AWS SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I want to send SMS to Indian numbers using AWS SNS service. I am using node.js code to trigger SNS APIs to send SMS. Success rate of SMS delivery is too low.

Not sure what can be done.

I checked post [AWS SNS is not sending SMS anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54242154/aws-sns-is-not-sending-sms-anymore) and [Amazon SNS -- Change Sender ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47415798/amazon-sns-change-sender-id?rq=1)
Also, raised query on AWS Forum - https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=303941

but could not get any pointers. Few more things done:

1. increased SMS maxPrice to $5 USD
2. Cloudwatch too does not show real time logs.
3. SMS API does not give any error in response

This is my code:

```
exports.sendSMS = function(msg, phoneNumber){
phoneNumber = "+91" + phoneNumber;

setMessageAttributes();
createSubscription(phoneNumber);

var params = {
  Message: msg,
  PhoneNumber: phoneNumber
};

// Create promise and SNS service object
var publishTextPromise = sns.publish(params).promise();

// Handle promise's fulfilled/rejected states
publishTextPromise.then(
  function(data) {
    console.log("MessageID is , SMS sent ------" + data.MessageId);
    console.log("JSON.stringify ------" + JSON.stringify(data));
    }).catch(
        function(err) {
        console.error(err, err.stack);
    });
  }

function setMessageAttributes(){
var messageParams = {
  attributes: {
    'DefaultSMSType': 'Transactional',//Also tried setting this to OTP, no use
    'DefaultSenderID': 'DevCare',
    }
};

function createSubscription(endpoint){
// Create subscribe/email parameters
var subscribeParams = {
  Protocol: 'SMS',
  TopicArn: 'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:xxxxxxx:US-xxxx', 
  Endpoint: endpoint
};
```

This is how response looks like for failed SMS:

> Subscription ARN is arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:351564314200:US-sendSMS:0725db58-xxxc-4764-af31-6825xxxxxx
>   MessageID is ------d5212bf1-9183-5da4-826e-7e96a48xxxxx
>   JSON.stringify ------{"ResponseMetadata":{"RequestId":"5d9bxxx9-319d-52b4-8979-xxxxxxxx"},"MessageId":"d521xxxxf1-91xx-5da4-826e-xxxxxxxx"}

Any help is highly appreciated. So that I can make a choice to go ahead or not with AWS SNS API.

Comment: One more information - I am able to send SMS everytime through AWS console using the publish option.

Comment: could you properly indent your code so its easier to read?  if you want to simply send text messages, you could consider using the AWS pinpoint service instead of SNS

Comment: Thanks for suggesting another option, but i am bit sceptical to go for another AWS service since not getting any help when the AWS API is not working as expected ! Also, my use case suffices just to send SMS for now